# Twitch API's request data always empty on specific route and only on browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oauth-2.0, twitch, twitch-api

#### Summary

I am building a website(react app) integrated with [twitch helix api](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-cheermotes).

I use the [Implicit grant flow](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/authentication/getting-tokens-oauth#implicit-grant-flow) to auth my website

When request this [https://api.twitch.tv/helix/videos](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos) route with `game_id` query param, it will always return an empty array

a picture from edge browser's network and console I printed
[image]
[image]

And the other routes are works fine.
like this route
[https://api.twitch.tv/helix/games/top](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-top-games)
[image]
or same route with `id` query param
[https://api.twitch.tv/helix/videos](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos)
[image]

**BUT** I use the api tester like [Thunder Client for VS Code](https://www.thunderclient.com/).
The [https://api.twitch.tv/helix/videos](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos) works fine
[image]

Also used the `C# NET6 ConsoleApp` to test on my windows 11
[image]

Found that this [https://api.twitch.tv/helix/videos](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos) route only works on server side, the client side could not works.

Only this [https://api.twitch.tv/helix/videos](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/api/reference#get-videos) route with `game_id` query param return an empty array while others (same api with different route or same route with other query param) works fine, it seems this is not a `CORS` error

#### Tried Solution

Had tried this [CORS - Wrong ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header](https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/cors-wrong-access-control-allow-origin-header/21714/9) on **twitch developer forums** to add a request header `'accept': 'application/vnd.twitchtv.v5+json'`, or renew my  twitch developer console's clientId.
But still didn't work

---

[My website on vercel](https://twitch-app-lac.vercel.app/)

Does anyone know this issue or I am missing something?

---

Comment: Other solution from twitch dev forum 
https://discuss.dev.twitch.tv/t/empty-data-return-by-https-dev-twitch-tv-docs-api-reference-get-videos/40452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set language request header to a empty string:

`headers.set('accept-language', '')`

It worked for me.

Comment: It works!! thanks for your help.  I have worked on this for weeks.......LOL